Why can't chrono::parse parse a POSIX date and time string?
I'm trying to use the <chrono> library to parse a POSIX date and time string, no matter what the global locale is, based on this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void printPosixDateString(string const &str) {
    istringstream stringStream{};
    stringStream.str(str);
    
    locale cLocale{"C"};//locale of C/POSIX language
    stringStream.imbue(cLocale);

    chrono::sys_seconds timeHolder{};//default value is unix time

    stringStream >> chrono::parse("%c", timeHolder);

    if(stringStream.fail()) {
        cout << "Error while parsing date string : " << stringStream.str() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << timeHolder;//should print the date object
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    locale french("fr_FR.UTF8");
    locale::global(french);
    cout.imbue(french);
    printPosixDateString("Fri Jul 5 14:58:21 2019");//must work no matter the global locale

    return 0;
}

The problem is that it always print the "Error while parsing date string: Fri Jul 5 14:58:21 2019" message.
Do you please have any explanations for this ?
I am on Arch Linux, Kernel: Linux 6.10.7-arch1-1, on a typical x86-64 computer.
I use g++ 14.2.1, tried with C++20 and C++23 (which gave the same outputs) and build my file like this:
g++ -std=c++20 -Wall -o main main.cpp
I hand-wrote the date string, in case I would have missed an invisible bizzare character.
I don't want to write the format myself, as I want to be able to use the "%c" locale datetime format, so that I can easily update this code to apply it to other locales.
I was expecting this output:
2019-07-5 14:58:21, but only got Error while parsing date string: Fri Jul 5 14:58:21 2019 for every of my tries.

You can try running this to get what the current locale uses as its date format to see if it matches your current string. credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73893070/is-there-any-way-in-c-to-format-date-according-to-system-location

@NathanOliver why %x (localized date representation) and not %c (standard date and time string) to match the parse? https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25f5a3bc7451aa72

@NathanOliver it gives me the output 09/23/24 (but it isn't the same format, so it is normal that this doesn't match the input I tried)

@RemyLebeau Doesn't chrono::parse("%c", timeHolder) expect timeHolder to be in the current locale's format?

@NathanOliver Yes, but the OP is imbue'ing the C locale beforehand, and then parsing using %c. chrono::parse() uses the same formatting as std::(get|put)_time. Also, %x only covers the date, but %c covers both date and time.

This appears to me to have nothing to do with locales.  It only has to do with %c being equivalent to %a %b %e %T %Y in the "C" locale.  If you strip all locale code out of the example it still fails.

This looks like it could be a gcc bug to me.  I recommend a bug report.  I note that your code works if you change "%c" to "%a %b %e %T %Y" which is what %c should expand to for the "C" locale.

Maybe the locale is not what we expect? Maybe OP should check with unset environment to get posix standard first?

@Klaus I tried to remove the setting of the global locale, but it didn't change anything.

The OP explicitly sets the "C" locale on the stringStream prior to the parse.

When I test it with both gcc and clang, std::chrono::parse("%c") is not able to parse the output of std::put_time("%c") using the same "C" locale. https://godbolt.org/z/7T9Wo7deM So it is not just a gcc bug

That appears to be the foundation of this error to me.

@Howard Hinnant do you mean this could be an error in both these compilers ? Or do they rely on a "chrono library" project ? I mean, where should I post a bug report ?

I recommend submitting a bug report to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/.  I wouldn't bother with clang at this time as their C++20 chrono support is still under (independent) development.

@RemyLebeau your "clang" test uses libstdc++ so is testing exactly the same thing as your GCC test, so is not proving anything. Use -stdlib=libc++ on godbolt to actually compare with a different implementation.

GCC's chrono::parse uses the std::time_get facet for parsing the %c format, so this is a bug in GCC's std::time_get rather than std::chrono::parse itself. I thought it might be https://gcc.gnu.org/PR45896 but changing 5 to 05 in the input string doesn't change anything. I'll comment further once it's reported to bugzilla, thanks for finding this problem.

Oh well this is fun, we simply use "" for the %c format in the C locale: https://gcc.gnu.org/cgit/gcc/tree/libstdc++-v3/config/locale/gnu/time_members.cc#n72 (see lines 79 )! At least it will be an easy fix.

Patch posted now: https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2024-September/663889.html
